# Alignment issue with Bullet point data in textbox

Tags: javascript, c#

When I copy bullet point data from outlook/MS Word and paste it to textbox and after click on submit button same data is sent to user's email through SMTP.
I am facing some alignment issue with same data.
Please see below images and suggest how to achieve this ?

**Data through SMTP :**
[image]

**Data Required :**

[image]

In 2nd Image the 2nd bullet point content is properly aligned.Please suggest.

Comment: The HTML code of both instances would be the key to your issue.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine
it is just textbox data which i am assigning to body of SMTP mail.

Comment: What do you think what makes the email look the way it does? I suspect the content of that textbox. When no styling is applied emails look the way it does. If you compare mail 1 from mail 2 (and I mean the HTML) you will see a lot of differences between then.